# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. copy from one list to another

Tags: c#, list, debugging, indexing, indexoutofrangeexception

I built following programm, but I get the out of range error. Basically I would like to copy values from one list to another (from `a` to `b`):

```
List<int> a = new List<int> { 99, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
List<int> b = new List<int>(6);

for ( int i = 0; i < a.ToArray().Length; i++ )
{
  a[i].ToString().Insert(0, b[i].ToString());
}

for ( int i = 0; i < a.ToArray().Length; i++ )
{
  Console.WriteLine(b[i]);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: `uzytkownik1` is empty... `ToArray()` is useless here.

Comment: I changed the names of the list references to help the eyes seeing the mistakes :o)

Comment: You should not call `ToString()` because you have a `List<int>` and not `List<string>` - remove both `ToString()` calls. You don't even have to write this code. Just use `b.AddRange(a);`

Comment: Change your first `a.ToArray().Length` to `a.Count`. And I suspect change the second one to `b.Count`.

Comment: What does `a[i].ToString()` result in? Is that what you expected?

Comment: What exact contents of `a` and `b` are you hoping for once the code has run?

Comment: Please don't vandalize any content, including your own.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the values from the first list to the second list by calling `ToList()` on the first list:

```
List<int> uzytkownik = new List<int>() { 99, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

List<int> uzytkownik1 = uzytkownik.ToList();//only values are copied, not the reference to the first list

for (int i = 0; i < uzytkownik1.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(uzytkownik1[i]);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

If you have to use a for loop then:

```
List<int> uzytkownik = new List<int>() { 99, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

List<int> uzytkownik1 = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < uzytkownik.Count; i++)
{
    uzytkownik1.Add(uzytkownik[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < uzytkownik1.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(uzytkownik1[i]);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Array.CopyTo method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copyto?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

The `List<T>` already has a method for that kind of work. [`List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.8)

```cs
List<int> a = new List<int> { 99, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
List<int> b = new List<int>(6);

b.AddRange( a );
```

[.net fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NIchCg)